# Quartz Composer, loop reloading text files (Command Line Tool)

Tags: quartz-composer

I have a .qtz that loads the last line of the latest .log file, to show the currently played song from a player.

Here is the source, with 2 .log files as an example: [LastTrack.zip](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2361587/LastTrack.zip) (read the instructions inside the .zip)

It works, but manually. You need to run it again from the Viewer to get the last played song. If you don´t do that, it always shows the same text, even if in the .log was a new track.

I would like to know if there is a way to make it work automatically (I have tried with LFO and Pulse with no results and making the script outputting some errors).

I have tried unplugging the LFO/Pulse and Enable/Disable by hand continuosly both Command Line Tool patches.

When doing it in "Get lastest .log file" patch, it outputted this error:

An exception was raised:

*** -[NSConcreteTask terminationStatus]: task still running

0x85b9bc55: -[QCContext nextExecutionTimeForPatch:time:arguments:]
0x85b9b9fe: -[QCGraphicsContext nextExecutionTimeForPatch:time:arguments:]
0x85b9b7e1: -[QCOpenGLContext nextExecutionTimeForPatch:time:arguments:]
0x0000d5f2
0x85be372d: -[QCView render:arguments:]
0x84ad6c49: -[NSView _drawRect:clip:]
0x84ad58bc: -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:]
0x84ad5c26: -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:]
0x84ad3f8e: -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:]
0x84ad4e5a: -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:]
0x84ad4e5a: -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:]
0x84ad3ab0: -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:]
0x84ad0362: -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:]
0x84a49b9a: -[NSView displayIfNeeded]
0x84a44a46: _handleWindowNeedsDisplay
0x85471b37: __CFRunLoopDoObservers
0x8544d464: __CFRunLoopRun
0x8544cdbf: CFRunLoopRunSpecific
0x8470591a: RunCurrentEventLoopInMode
0x8470567d: ReceiveNextEventCommon
0x847055d8: BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode
0x84a19e64: _DPSNextEvent
0x84a197a9: -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]
0x849df48b: -[NSApplication run]

When doing it in "Get the last line of the .log file" patch, it outputted this error (i think is the same):

An exception was raised:

*** -[NSConcreteTask terminationStatus]: task still running

0x85b9bc55: -[QCContext nextExecutionTimeForPatch:time:arguments:]
0x85b9b9fe: -[QCGraphicsContext nextExecutionTimeForPatch:time:arguments:]
0x85b9b7e1: -[QCOpenGLContext nextExecutionTimeForPatch:time:arguments:]
0x0000d5f2
0x85be372d: -[QCView render:arguments:]
0x84ad6c49: -[NSView _drawRect:clip:]
0x84ad58bc: -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:]
0x84ad5c26: -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:]
0x84ad3f8e: -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:]
0x84ad4e5a: -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:]
0x84ad4e5a: -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:]
0x84ad3ab0: -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:]
0x84ad0362: -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:]
0x84a49b9a: -[NSView displayIfNeeded]
0x84a44a46: _handleWindowNeedsDisplay
0x85471b37: __CFRunLoopDoObservers
0x8544d464: __CFRunLoopRun
0x8544cdbf: CFRunLoopRunSpecific
0x8470591a: RunCurrentEventLoopInMode
0x8470567d: ReceiveNextEventCommon
0x847055d8: BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode
0x84a19e64: _DPSNextEvent
0x84a197a9: -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]
0x849df48b: -[NSApplication run]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Command Line Tool` patch updates only when its input ports change.  So, in your case, you could attach something that changes periodically (the `Signal` private patch, for example) to an unused input, such as "Standard In".

Comment: Hi Smokris, thank you so much for your answer. I have been searching for that private patch, but I haven´t found it. My QC version is 4.0. Have you tried it with the LastTrack.qtz and it works? (remember I said before that i.e. the LFO to the CLT "Standard In" makes the script crashes after a short time running) Thank you again.

Comment: Go to the Quartz Composer menu, hold Option, then click Preferences.  Then select the new "(System)" tab, and enable the QCShowPrivatePatches setting.  Restart QC, and you should see `Signal`.  I did test it with `Signal`, and it does seem to work.

Comment: Hi, after trying several configurations, It seems to work, with 2 Signal patches (Mode: Every 5 seconds), attached to both "Enable" in CTL patches. The issue now is the same than with the LFO/Pulse: the script stops/crashes after a short period of time (30sec, 1 min, whatever), and when you run it again, the text in the Viewer is showed in a random scale. It gets normal when you restart LastTrack. Can you give me an idea about how did you make it work in your test, please?

Comment: Regarding the random viewport scaling --- UGH, I forgot how awful the `Command Line Tool` patch is.  I'm working on an update to Kineme FileTools --- use that instead, when it's ready.

Comment: Ok Smokris, I´ll wait till the update, if there´s no solution at this moment. How long would it take? The stopping/crashing issue is another CLT bug also? Thank you so much.

Comment: Does anyone knows why this composition crashes after a short time running, please?